# iOS application collapse on taking picture

Tags: ios, image, delphi, camera, firemonkey

I have programmed iOS application that (between others) takes picture of something and sends it to the server. To achieve this effect I use standard action TakePicture and I have my logic in event OnDidFinishTaking. After execute takePicture I get standard camera application to get picture and approve it to my application. On approval, OnDidFinishTaking event fires.... usually, but sometimes (30%) application collapse (finishes... is killed - don't know how to call it differently) when I approve picture. I set brakepoint on very beginning OnDidFinishTaking event and know, that in that cases program does not even runs this event.

I use RadStudio XE5 with update 1. iOS is version 7.0.4 on new iPad.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an out of memory event.  In your simulator, from the menu, choose "Simulate memory warning".  Do this 2 or 3 times in a row.  If you have an issue handling memory warnings this will "crash" your app.

If this is the case, follow this guide to reduce the memory usage of your app:  http://www.raywenderlich.com/2696/

You should also look at this page about memory and performance: 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/PerformanceTuning/PerformanceTuning.html

Comment: I see... You're right. I worked on decreasing memory usage. I unload everithing that is no longer used, I have no pictures in my application (instead of one PNG 128x128 on first screen). My app on startup takes 36MB of memmory (the only way I can check it is to use Pad-Info app) - it's quite little I think. There is a lot of other, much bigger applications that works :(

Comment: I found that eg. switching between applications before taking picture on between one picture and another helps (maybe some system tiding up?), but do you maybe know, how to invoke this behaviour in Firemonkey without switching between applications or closing and oppening same form in application?

Comment: It's possible that your app is crashing for a threading or multiasking issue, but like there is a lot going on with your app.  I need more information to be able to help you.  Please try to narrow down your problem before replying

Answer (score 0):

ok... My application was build with many different forms. Everyone was loaded and destroyed dynamically but whatever I had done, didn't help.
Finally, I rebuild application to use tabs instead of forms. Now application uses almost same memory in my iPad (much less than other applications, but fortunately, does not collapse.

SO... if you have problem with memory in your application and nothing helps, try to use tabs instead of forms. Even if it takes same memory, it seems that management is different and it works better.

M.